# Using CASE statement to exclude specific healthcare claims data

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have two Snowflake tables for member health claims. Table A has all of a clinic's claims, and Table B is just the clinic's claims filtered down to a specific year and specific services that I'm interested in.

I would like to exclude member's claims from Table B (the filtered down table) if that member had any other services done on the same day (this data would be from Table A).

Example: Member C is in Table B. Member C is in Table A and has other services done on the same date as Table B's services. Raise a flag for the rows where that is the case (the rows highlighted in red in the two images).

[image: Table A: All Claims]

[image: Table B: Specific Claims]

I have tried to use CASE statement with the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
B.*,
(CASE
    WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
        FROM TableA -- Table with all the claims --
        WHERE A.MemberID = B.MemberID 
        AND (A.Date = B.Date)
        AND A.Service != 1234) -- For claims for services I do NOT want, but are on the same day --
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS EXCLUSION_FLAG
FROM TableB B -- Table with specific claims --
```

I am trying to get a flag for all of Table B's members' rows (these are members with the specific services and year that I am interested in) and see which rows should be excluded. I am trying to get this on a row-level basis. A member may have *some* claims that should be excluded, but that does not mean the member should be excluded entirely.

I am getting mixed results with the flag I created (I saw that one member's particular row returned a 0 when I expected it to be a 1). I am not really sure how else to approach this problem. Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi you can do a left outer join between the Table_A and Table_B  , on the columns MemberID and Date, if the value in Table_B is Not null then that means on the same day for a member a record exists, then you can flag that row.

Comment: Hi @HimanshuKandpal, thank you for that suggestion, I actually didn't even know a LEFT OUTER JOIN could exist. Just to check with you: I would keep my CASE statement the same after I add in a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: there is a mistake in your example data, your table b value `(1, 'x', 202003),` does not exist in table a, and you have what appears a typo.

Comment: @Michael, you can use Case When table_b.MemberID IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end inc_flg and in the query you can have a Where clause, where inc_flg = 0

Answer (score 0):

so your example data is inconsistant, so changing it to  "work" as highlighted:

```
with table_a(m_id, service, date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'x', 202001),
        (1, 'y', 202001),
        (1, 'x', 202002),
        (1, 'x', 202003),
        (1, 'x', 202002),
        (2, 'x', 202101),
        (2, 'x', 202102),
        (2, 'z', 202103),
        (3, 'x', 202105),
        (3, 'y', 202105),
        (3, 'x', 202106)      
), table_b(m_id, service, date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'x', 202001),
        (1, 'x', 202002),
        (1, 'x', 202003),
        (2, 'x', 202101),
        (3, 'x', 202105),
        (3, 'x', 202106)
)
```

we can use a left join to show the rows we want to exclude:

```
select * 
from table_b as b
left join table_a as a
    on b.m_id = a.m_id 
        and b.date = a.date
        and b.service != a.service
order by 1,3;
```

gives:

[image]

so now to filter those rows out with `where a.m_id is null` and given we know the a side of the join is empty, we should change to only using `b.*` values:

```
select 
    b.* 
from table_b as b
left join table_a as a
    on b.m_id = a.m_id 
        and b.date = a.date
        and b.service != a.service
where a.m_id is null
order by 1,3;
```

[image]